# Rhino Mocks stubbing an event with ref parameter

Tags: c#, events, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to call an event from my mocked object. I'm doing it like:

```
importObject.Raise(x => x.RequestImportLevel += null, false, false, true, importLevel);
```

the last parameter required to be passed by reference. So, i'm getting an exception

> Parameter #4 is System.Int16 but
>   should be System.Int16&

What can I do to handle this?

If the problem is in Rhino Mocks - are there any other frameworks that cleanly support this out-of-the-box?

Comment: Any way to change the event to NOT require a ref parameter?  A dedicated EventArgs with a read/write property could easily replace the ref parameter.

Comment: unfortunately, not.
Actually, it's an event from legacy COM component, and there's no way to change it to an EventArgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This object implemented an interface, so I just created a dummy class, make it inherit from IEventWithRefParameter and introduced a function like

```
    public virtual void RaiseRequestImportLevelEvent(bool hasYc, bool hasWc, bool hasDc, ref short chosenLevel)
    {
        if (RequestImportLevel != null)
        {
            RequestImportLevel(hasYc, hasWc, hasDc, ref chosenLevel);
        }
    }
```

Now I'm using an instance of this dummy class in my tests and when I'd like to raise an event I just call this function.

not nearly a clean solution, but at least it does the trick.